# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in "mysql status"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have checked all entries above but it solve not my problem
mysql start's normally and I can enter in by mmysql -u root -p and the password, this is ok!

but when I check the mysql status so I get the following message:

```
Jul 04 13:29:46 raspi21 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
Jul 04 13:29:47 raspi21 mysqld[861]: 2022-07-04 13:29:47 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 861 ...
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[910]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[913]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[913]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[913]: Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[913]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[913]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Jul 04 13:29:48 raspi21 /etc/mysql/debian-start[920]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
```

I don't understand the argument "(using password: NO)

thanks for any info's for help
Max

Comment: Try **SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'**, it almost feels like root was granted access without password.

Comment: root@localhost is with password  >>>   MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for root@localhost;
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*64A8B35F2806DF1F33AF2170D6501F56E0D7F997' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                          |
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]>

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to access MySQL without using password when the user has a password set. What command do you use exactly when checking mysql status? Also the log suggests the command done is /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade for which you can actually pass a user/pass like: **/usr/local/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p**, so try running this command first adding -p switch.

Comment: no, I can access by root + pw as well, this is not the problem; the message come from the msql-status --- my be it's mean, I have to define "root@localhost" without password???

Answer (score 6):

The `/etc/debian/debian-start` is starting the upgrade and using `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` as the store of username/password for `mysql_upgrade`.

As the credentials here don't match what you've changed the password to it can't upgrade.

Comment: So apparently my colleague has changed the password. Now what?

Comment: Make the password in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` match what it was changed to.