# How can I restart mysql without getting this error?

Tags: mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

But I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I then enter and can enter mysql without any problem.

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -ppassword databasename
```

My question is that, can I restart mysql service without getting that error by maybe supplying hostname and password straight away.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856498/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-n/72864537#72864537)

Answer (score 0):

somtimes error occurs but changing mysql password can solve the error.
and once you changed your password, you're error free.